# Column name field showing multiple time in php?

Tags: php

I am searching records and records are displaying from database, but column name is repeating.Please check below images.

```
<table border="1" align="center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>User id</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM newrecords_1 WHERE CONCAT( First_name, ' ',Last_name ) LIKE '%$name%'  ORDER BY `First_name` ASC"; 
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>

        <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['First_name'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['Last_name'];?></td>
         </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php

        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

**What i am getting**

[image]

**What i need**

[image]

after added html code on header getting output
[image]

Comment: Create the header before you start the loop. You are recreating the header for every entry.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Martavis...right while loop is recreating...

Comment: @Hybreeder move tale code outside of loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your table code outside of the loop like below :-

```
<table border="1" align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>User id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM newrecords_1 WHERE CONCAT( First_name, ' ',Last_name ) LIKE '%$name%'  ORDER BY `First_name` ASC"; 
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
    <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['First_name'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Last_name'];?></td>
     </tr>
    <?php } } else { echo "0 results";}?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Mr.Anant ,I tried your code but only single record is display and rest of record are display in one line not in table

Comment: @Hybreeder  you are not using code correctly. your `</tbody></table>` is still inside the loop. put it outside. check my code once again

Comment: Absolutely correct... now working perfectly...Thank you very much...Working now

Comment: @Hybreeder  glad to help you.:):)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting header part after every fetching because you are using header part also in loop. Place header part above loop and keep only
below code in loop.

```
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['First_name'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Last_name'];?></td>
     </tr>
```